# How to add functions to an application?

Tags: workbench

Some time ago I created a documented application with the workbench. Now I want to add some functions to this application. So in the project I added a usage message in the .m file, such as

```
bla::usage="bla[] is a test.";
```

Then indeed the workbench shows, under `PacletInfo.m`, `Documentation`, `bla::missing file`. So I click on `Create Symbol Pages`, then on `Select Missing` (`bla` is in the list and checked) and press `OK`. Nothing happens, no pages are created.

I can select `bla::missing file` and then press `Add Page`. Then the reference page `bla.nb` is created, but it does not mention the usage message.

This suggests that there is something wrong with my usage message. But when I load the application and enter `?bla`, the usage message appears.

Therefore my, a little bit desparate question: what is the correct way of adding new functions to an application in the workbench? Any help is highly appreciated.